# Error while installing php5-gd on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

(I am to install it inside a phusion Ubuntu Docker)

Comment: I'm voting to close the question. Your link is wrong or out of date there's nothing anybody can do to help you apart from google on your behalf.

Comment: You have provided very little information but it seems that the docker image/container you are running has outdated apt package lists. Try running:
`sudo apt-get update` to fetch latest package data. FYI, your package had been replaced by libfreetype6_2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb